# How to manage common source files in source control?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, open-source, bitbucket

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

`CommonUtilities`, `DataStructure1` and `DataStructure2` contain source files used by one or more projects.

I would like to publish one or more projects as open source using Mercurial and BitBucket. But I don't know how to manage the source files used by one or more projects.

I am new to source control and to software development in general, so I would like to know the best practices in this kind of situation.

Should I:

1. Include the common source files in more repositories as needed? 
   (that is `hg add` them to two or more repositories)
2. Include the common files in some other way than `hg add`?
3. Do something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3: Do something completely different.

You can use the [subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) feature: keep the common files in a different repo, then reference them from your repository.

Comment: Thank you! It seems interesting and looks like this is exactly what I need. But why is it considered a feature of last resort? Are you in a similar situation? Do you have any advice on what can go wrong?

Comment: Mercurial documentation provides [a list of recommendations](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=Subrepositories#Recommendations) for when using subrepositories to avoid problems. There is also a page explaining the [features of last resort](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort). I've never really used subrepositories myself: I'd try to solve the problem by releasing versions: CommonUtilities-0.1, CommonUtilities-0.2, then referencing them on my other projects, even if they would be only internal tools.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve the issue by wrong tool. The best way to manage such situation is a dependency management tool (look at [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)).